# oscilloscope of speaker input stops rendering after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, animation, audio, canvas, web-audio-api

The following script reads the audio from the user's microphone and renders an oscilloscope on a html canvas.

The source is taken from an example of the mozilla developer network: [Visualizations with Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API)

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7j8pktp/

```
mozGetUserMedia
```

(note: code has no fork mechanism for different browsers: works only with firefox)

It works fine for a few seconds and then immediately stops rendering.

Whereas this works totally stable: http://mdn.github.io/voice-change-o-matic/

---

The problem can be reduced to the following code. The microphone activation icon (next to the the address bar in firefox) disappears after about 5 seconds:

```
navigator.mozGetUserMedia({audio: true},                           
    function() {}, function() {} );
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/b7j8pktp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Firefox. Just take the stream from the getUserMedia call and hook it up to the window like so:

`navigator.mozGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
  window.stream = stream;
  // rest of the code
}, function err() {
  // handle error
});`

Hopefully we can get it fixed soon. The problem is that we're failing to add a reference to the stream when we do the `AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource` call, so that the stream is not referenced by anything anymore when the `getUserMedia` callback returns, and it is collected by the cycle collector when it runs, that is, a couple seconds later.

You can follow along in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934512.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't get it working: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Le886fqt/

Comment: I made a typo, getUserMedia is on navigator, not on window.